# How can I remove the "Other" inbox folder from Facebook

Tags: facebook

On numerous occasions I have missed out on ever so important Facebook messages due to the "Basic Filtering" Facebook offers, and by offering that, it blocks all messages I receive from people whom I have no mutual friends with.
These messages, instead of going to my Inbox folder, go to the Other folder, and therefore no notification about such messages are received.

How do I get rid of the "Other" inbox, so I can actually be notified and properly receive all messages sent to me?

Answer (score 2):

There's no option to get rid of the "Other" inbox for now, neither is there a way to be notified of messages there.